# How to read temperature stored in a IButton device?

Tags: android

I need to store temperature in a IButton device and show all temperature on a graph when this Ibutton is connected to mobile. But I only get the current temperature from device.How to get previously stored temperature from IButton device. I am using [IButton](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5705) link as a reference.